# How do I fix encoding in a data frame regardless of its row or column in R(using dplyr)?

Tags: r, dplyr

*original title "how to replace string" updated to "fix encoding" because that is the question that is answered here.*

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] countrycode_0.17 dplyr_0.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1 magrittr_1.0.1 parallel_3.1.1 Rcpp_0.11.3    tools_3.1.1
```

I have a data frame with certain errors during importing from a web source. I am looking to replace those with strings that I think are correct, I am learning R and dplyr so knowing how to do this might help me in bigger problems of cleaning data.

Please find the image with erros in the 20th and 31st row where we see "UniversitÃ¤t" instead of "Universitat" and "LinkÃ¶ping" instead of "Linkaping"

I know I can look for the row and column and try to replace them , but in case of larger data frames or datasets I would not be able to find all instances.

Since I know the discrepancy i would want to search for the word itself and replace it. Just the word . I know it is a part of a string. But still i want to deal with just that part of the string, can I do that?

any help is appreciated, I would also appreciate it if you could all possible approaches and solutions to this porblem both simple and complex, It would help me learn faster, Thanks,[image]

```
                          name     country
1                             TU Dortmund     Germany
2                             TU Dortmund     Germany
3                   Maastricht University Netherlands
4         University of the Fraser Valley      Canada
5                      Queen's University      Canada
6                       Aarhus University     Denmark
7                   University Of Alberta      Canada
8                       Deakin University   Australia
9                    Macquarie University   Australia
10 National University Of Ireland, Galway     Ireland
11                      Vienna University     Austria
12       National University of Singapore   Singapore
13                     Erasmus University Netherlands
14          Radboud Universiteit Nijmegen Netherlands
15           Vrije Universiteit Amsterdam Netherlands
16                    University of Otago New Zealand
17            National College Of Ireland     Ireland
18                University College Cork     Ireland
19             Irish Management Institute     Ireland
20                  UniversitÃ¤t Konstanz     Germany
21 Otto Von Guericke University Magdeburg     Germany
22        University of Technology Sydney   Australia
23                 Dublin City University     Ireland
24 Institute Of Technology Blanchardstown     Ireland
25      Kth Royal Institute Of Technology      Sweden
26                       Aalto University     Finland
27                     Dalarna University      Sweden
28                 University Of Helsinki     Finland
29                      Aarhus University     Denmark
30              University College Dublin     Ireland
31                  LinkÃ¶ping University      Sweden
32                     Aalborg University     Denmark
33         Dublin Institute Of Technology     Ireland
34                        York University      Canada
35                  Maastricht University Netherlands
36                     Utrecht University Netherlands
```

Comment: Please consider showing the dataset using `dput` or just paste the few lines instead of showing an `image` file.  This might be an `encoding` issue.  Please show `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I am having `R 3.1.2` with `[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Hey akrun ,Thanks for the reply,  I read the csv file using your code, it worked , it read fine, thanks. but I would still like to know if I can replace a part of the string regardless of column or row position within a data frame..

Comment: I was trying to upvote your comment but I guess I did not do it right, lost your last comment regarding the code for replacing , could you please post it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could correct this in a couple of ways.

1. Read the file with the proper encoding (`UTF-8`)

   ```
   read.csv2(file("filename.csv", encoding="UTF-8"))
   ```
2. After reading the file, apply functions to convert to the `UTF-8` encoding

   ```
   library(stringi)
   df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) stri_encode(x, "", "UTF-8"))
   ```